# Using database datetime

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a table user_rol, on this table is a filed expiration_date, this field is used to "delete" rols when expiration_date is < than now/now. When a rol is "deleted" I need to set expiration_date to today/now, but I want the today/now to be the one from the database server.

How can i do that?

This is what I have now:

```
user_rolrol = db_cm.user_rol.Where(r => r.id_rol == idRol && r.id_user == idUser).FirstOrDefault();

rol.expiration_date = DateTime.Now;
db_cm.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: not the answer but: why don't use UTC time? (DateTime.UTCNow is the same on each computer)

Comment: @trippino I don't think that's the case. It's still generated from the system time which can easily be different across computers. In fact, `DateTime.Now` is generated from `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: @Mansfield no, in fact I wrote "not the answer". I wrote it just because I think that he needs the server time in order to have the datetime without regarding the time zone, and this can be achieved also using UTC.

Comment: @trippino Provided, of course, that the local time is correct.

Comment: @Mansfield Yes of course (maybe this is the main reason to avoid using my method for real-world cases)

Answer (score 0):

You could always run an object query against your EF context and then assign the result to your `user_rolrol` object before saving it.

Like so:

```
ObjectQuery<DateTime> date = new ObjectQuery<DateTime>("select Getdate()", db_cm)
DateTime now = date.Single();

user_rolrol = db_cm.user_rol.Where(r => r.id_rol == idRol && r.id_user == idUser).FirstOrDefault();

rol.expiration_date = now; //this from the objectquery against your context
db_cm.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: context.Database.SqlQuery in EF5